# Fill out numbers in list by sequence in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column or list called "**Index**", which contain numbers from 1 to n with an increment of 1.

I also have a column or list called "**Number**" which I want to populate based on the index column and the **sequence number given in cell C3**.

Now the sequence number is 5 - therefore want to populate index 1-5 in numbers column with 1, and for example index 16-20 with 4. If the sequence number was 10, then I would want to populate index 1-10 in numbers column with 1, and index 11-20 with 2.

Basically I want the number column to contain number, but increase with one after populating as many cells as the sequence number.

I need a formula in the number column that can do this for me.

[image: See picture:]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
=CEILING(<INDEX>/n,1)
```

Where '' is your range of index-numbers and 'n' what you call the sequence-number. In your sample this would translate to `=CEILING(B6:B38/C3,1)` for versions of Excel that work with dynamic arrays and can spill the result in a single go, *or* `=CEILING(B6/C3,1)` for older versions which you need to drag down.

Comment: Ceiling was the perfect formula. I did get what I wanted by this input: =CEILING(B6:B38/C3,1)

Answer (score 1):

I got what I wanted by @JvdV's formula suggestions CEILING().

In this case I did

```
=CEILING(indexcolumn/sequencenumber,1)
```

or

```
=CEILING(B6:B38/C3,1)
```

Comment: No need to copy my post. Please, if it has answered your question you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left of the answer.

Comment: Yep, sorry. Your formula was correct, but your suggested input in the formula was wrong in context of what I asked. But thank you. Checkmarked your answer.

Comment: I see you edited to the correct formula input now :) @JvdV